# Error find and rename recursively in linux

Tags: linux

I am trying to find and rename files recursively in many sub-directories using the command below:

In essence, I'm trying to rename files that start with '_p2' and replace '_p2' so that they start with '_p4'.

```
 find /XXX/YYY -name '_p2*' -exec rename _p2 _p4 '_p2*'
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this error

```
find: paths must precede expression
```

I tried using just find without the rename and it works fine. Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `{}\;` at the end:

```
find /XXX/YYY -name '_p2*' -exec rename _p2 _p4 {}\;
```

`{}` passes the file name to `rename` and `\;` terminates the `rename` command.

Answer (score 1):

YOu forgot to terminate the -exec:

```
find /path/ -name '_p2*' -exec rename _p2 _p4 {} \;
```

Comment: why you answering this? I already gave an answer. For me it looks like you've copied it.